# Grouping dataframe by period with multi-index

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am currently working with a large dataframe consisting of weekly ocurrences of a disease in some brazilian states from 1941 to 2019. I want to group them by state and s specific periods of time, but I just can't do it properly because I always end up creating a multi-index that I can't work to.

Here is the layout of my dataframe:

`df.head()`:

[image: df.head()]

`df.tail()`

[image: df.tail()]

The label **dt_sintoma** is the period of time where the ocurrences were computes.

The label **municipio** is the state where the ocurrences happened and **co_municipio** is a geo-code regarding such state.

I am triyng to group them by states and then group them by periods (semester, months, trimester etc.).

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['municipio',df.index]).sum()
```

and got:

[image]

Now I would like to group them by periods, but now I have a multi-index:

```
df.groupby(['municipio',df.index]).sum().index = 
MultiIndex([('Aracaju', '1950-08-06'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-08-13'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-08-20'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-08-27'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-09-03'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-09-10'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-09-17'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-09-24'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-10-01'),
            ('Aracaju', '1950-10-08'),
            ...
            ('Vitória', '2019-03-03'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-03-10'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-03-17'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-03-24'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-03-31'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-04-07'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-04-14'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-04-21'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-04-28'),
            ('Vitória', '2019-05-05')],
           names=['municipio', 'dt_sintoma'], length=118347)
```

I just can't do this grouping properly. Also, when grouping by some period and summing up the ocurrences, I can't sum **co_municipio** because it is a code and should not be modified.

Comment: You gave one of grouping keys as *specific period of time*,
but *dt_sintoma* column (index) contains **exact** dates not periods.
Specify what do you mean by *period*. A year, a month or other period?

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion I made. The data were weekly collected, so there is an exact date (index) where the data was inserted into the database. The period I want to group the data is variable. I want to group them into different periods (leading to different dataframes), like semester, trimester.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will perform grouping on several various periods (and state).
In my answer I will show how to group by **month** (and state).

For test purpose I created the following DataFrame:

```
           municipio  occorencas
dt_sintoma                      
2019-04-14  Brasilia        1283
2019-04-21  Brasilia        1139
2019-05-05  Brasilia         547
2019-05-12  Brasilia          25
2019-04-10   Aracaju         100
2019-04-20   Aracaju         120
2019-06-12   Aracaju          50
2019-06-21   Aracaju          16
2018-01-10   Vitória          33
2018-01-20   Vitória          60
```

As the state code is not used, I didn't include it.

To perform the required grouping, run:

```
df.set_index(df.index.to_period('M')).groupby(
    [pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'municipio']).sum()
```

The result (for my test data) is:

```
                      occorencas
dt_sintoma municipio            
2018-01    Vitória            93
2019-04    Aracaju           220
           Brasilia         2422
2019-05    Brasilia          572
2019-06    Aracaju            66
```

As you can see:

1. The first trick is to change the index from exact dates
   to periods of the required length, to have period labels like *2019-04*
   (a whole month, not *2019-04-30* - the last day of this month).
2. Then there is a 2-level grouping on index with the same frequency (*M*)
   and *municipio*.
3. And finally, for each group the sum of occurrences is computed.

If you want to compute sums grouping e.g. by year, change *M* frequency to *Y*
(in both places).

If you want to group first by state and then by month, reverse the *groupby*
argument:

```
['municipio', pd.Grouper(freq='M')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same approach but didn't change the index. It worked perfectly